# how to show pdf inside the aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, pdf

net mvc 3. I want to display the pdf file as a part of aspx page for preview purpose.[image]

i don't want to use IFrame control. can we do this ?

Comment: Why don't you want to use an `iframe`?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I know you said no frames, but Google PDF viewer seems to be the most popular:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=http://example.com/mypdf.pdf&embedded=true"
  style="width:718px; height:700px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

And you can try:

```
<embed src="http://yoursite.com/the.pdf" width="500" height="375">
```

[Best Way to Embed PDF in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/291813/best-way-to-embed-pdf-in-html)

Comment: You beat me to it by literally 20 seconds. Damn!

Comment: google PDF is good way. but need privacy as per client policies. so it will better to keep the pdf file in my app domain in file structure and render them as part of the Page. niether to capture overall page or open in new tab. just user would like to click the preview and async call goes to pdf file to be render... thanks guys your directions are helpfull but need more focus on the privacy and policies.

Comment: Google iframe option needs the files to be publicly available that could be harmful for some scenarios. Any how, it works for me.